# Google Speech API gRPC sync request processes first word(s) only

Tags: delphi, grpc, google-cloud-speech

Google Speech API via gRPC recognizes first few words only. Tested using several short (<10s) audio files in several (wav, flac) formats.

I am trying to get Google's speech API to work with Delphi using gRPC. (Calling the Speech API from Delphi using JSON works OK, but does not support streaming)
As Google does not support Delphi as gRPC client, I use [Grijjy's protocolbuffers](https://github.com/grijjy/GrijjyFoundation) for Serializing/Deserializing audio request/response, and [Grijjy's scalable sockets](https://github.com/grijjy/DelphiScalableClientSockets) for the http/2 request.

As I think the code is too large to share here, I created a MVCE. A zip file containing source code (Delphi 10.3), executable and audio file can be found [here](https://ayuus.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/GoogleSpeechMVCE.zip). The audio file contains the text "How old is the Brooklyn Bridge", which is flawlessly recognized when calling the Speech API via JSON.

To run the executable, only a [Google API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) is necessary. Necessary support file nghttp2.dll is included. After sending a request, a messagebox is displayed containing the deserialized response. I checked this is the complete Google response by checking response data size. The response only shows "how old", where I would have expected a full recognized sentence. No errors are returned, confidence factor is also returned.

To compile the source code, Grijjy's code as mentioned above must downloaded from Github and the folder(s) containing the downloaded code made available to the Delphi project.

Also, for Google to accept the request, in grijjy.http, line 1215 needs to modified from

```
 FInternalHeaders.AddOrSet('host', FURI.Host);
```

to

```
FInternalHeaders.AddOrSet(':authority', FURI.Host);
```

(I failed to create a pull request for this earlier today, will try again later)

During my debugging efforts, I also checked response headers (200 OK), also tried other files (same issue).

For now, I do not know how to continue. Any ideas regarding how to get find the cause (or even better, a solution:-) of this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be hitting one of the API quotas Google enforces?

Comment: There was a very similar q a couple of weeks ago about the speech API only returning the first two words to a Delphi app, so maybe it is a common limitation or config problem, but it seems to have been deleted.  I suggest you do some googling.

Comment: I am not hitting an API quotum, as JSON requests are processed OK.

Comment: The previous question was mine, too. I was told to create a MVCE, so that is what I tried.

Comment: I will try and look at your example project, since I wrote a good portion of that stuff you are using

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.  Have you tried other wav files to see if the problem persists.  What if you append extra empty audio to the end of the file?  There are lots of bugs in the speech apis of Google as well and it is more likely a bug understanding the wav file input.

Comment: I did not try other wav files (btw this wav file comes from Google). I also tried a short flac file created myself, same issue. So I suspect it is either a bug in serialization, or a bug at the other end. As this is only a first step to my end goal: performing real time streaming speech recognition from a Delphi application, I tried streaming recognition, too. There I found alike issues, depending on buffer size. Sending streaming data in buffers of 1024Kb recogizes everything, sending all in one buffer recognizes only first two words.

Comment: As sending the same data using WinHttp does work as expected, issue must be somewhere in nghttp2.dll usage.

Comment: The link to your mcve is now broken. Did you resolve your issue?